# How get context Confluence using atlassian-python-api?

Tags: python, confluence, confluence-rest-api, atlassian-python-api

I want to get context page confluence,
used python module atlassian-python-api

https://github.com/AstroTech/atlassian-python-api

found example how to create new page

```
from atlassian import Confluence

confluence = Confluence(
    url='http://localhost:8090',
    username='admin',
    password='admin')

status = confluence.create_page(
    space='DEMO',
    title='This is the title',
    body='This is the body. You can use <strong>HTML tags</strong>!')

print(status)
```

How get context, example for this page 
http://conf01:8080/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=111113
?

Comment: Have you checked example folder? I believe they do have it https://github.com/AstroTech/atlassian-python-api/blob/master/examples/confluence-page-get.py

Comment: Checked example folder and already found solve. Please, write answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [example](https://github.com/AstroTech/atlassian-python-api/blob/master/examples/confluence-page-get.py), you can either use `get_page_by_title` or `get_page_by_id` for getting page content.